# JFrame large grid map

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm trying to make a large grid map of 160x120 JButtons with JFrame but it's too much to fit on the window.

How can I overcome this?

```
public class DisplayTable extends JFrame {
    public static void main() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("puzzle layout");
        //frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(3200, 800);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        panel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(0,0,0,0));
        panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(12,16));

        for(int i=0; i<120; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<160; j++) {
                 JButton temp = new JButton("1");
                 panel.add(temp);
            }
        }
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `JScrollPane` to wrap the `panel` ... also, you should use `pack` instead of `setSize`, but only after you've added all your components to the screen

See [How to use scroll panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for more details